# gnuplot - no space between graph and png image edge

Tags: gnuplot

How to create a .png image in `gnuplot` to see no spaces between graph itself and image edges.
I use

```
set terminal pngcairo size 800,600 enhanced
```

I want exactly 800x600 image. And want all 0X axis correspond to [0..800] interval, and all 0Y correspond to [0..600] interval.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you want to set the margins to 0.  Here is an example script:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 800,600 enhanced
set output 'output.png'

set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0

#unset tics

plot sin(x) # notitle
```

This way the plot will fill the canvas exactly.  You can type `help set margin` in gnuplot for details.  (Uncomment the comments in my example if you want a slightly cleaner plot.)